# UIDevice orientation not working as expected

Tags: ios, uideviceorientation

I am having a problem with device orientation. I have an iPhone app that has some views, all of them should not rotate except one. So I take a look inside `Info.plist`; I select two device orientations, portrait and lanscape, and in the views I dont want to rotate so I put this.

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return NO;
}
```

but all the views rotate. Even with these lines in them. If change `Info.plist` to support no portrait. It works ok, just the view that I want to rotate, I put

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

And it does not work. I use iOS 6. Also tried

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
```

Comment: Is this iOS 6? In iOS 6 those two methods don't get called anymore.

Comment: YES, it works on iOS 5, but not iOS 6. What should I use on iOS 6?

Comment: doesn't anyone know the answer?

Comment: Read the UIViewController description: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying exactly the orientations you would like the view to rotate to. For instance, if you want portrait only use this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

For rotating to all views, you can still use YES, although this will allow it to rotate to the upside down view which isn't always desired. To get both landscape orientations and right side up portrait, use this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```